# Python's socket is compaining about data type

Tags: python-3.x

I'm playing around with sockets and I've got this block of code:

```
while True:
        client_socket.send(bytes('<BHP> ', 'utf-8'))
        cmd_buffer = ''
        while '\n' not in cmd_buffer:
            cmd_buffer += client_socket.recv(1024)
        response = run_command(cmd_buffer)
        client_socket.send(response)
```

I know in Python 3 `socket.send()` method accepts bytes-like arguments.
When I use the syntax `bytes(string, [encoding])` it throws an error saying:
`TypeError: must be str, not bytes`. When I edit the code to take in string
like this:

```
client_socket.send('<BHP> ')
```

It throws:  `TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'`
So what does it want me to pass in ? Bytes or a string ???

Comment: Are you sure that both errors are actually coming from the `.send()` line?  You also have a similar problem on the `.recv()` line, since you're trying to append the incoming bytes to a str variable.

Comment: @jasonharper  I'm pretty sure. The traceback throws the error at the point when it hits the line with `client_socket.send('<BHP> ')` Documentation is saying that this method accepts either iterable of integers (list) or a string with encoding. I went for the latter. Sooner or later I'm gonna figure out how to make it work.

Comment: I don't know what's actually going wrong - what you describe seems impossible - but here's a workaround that may get you going a bit further: try `client_socket.send(b'<BHP> ')`.  Specifying the literal to be a bytestring avoids the need to call `bytes()` at all.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
client_socket.sendall()
```

instead of

```
client_socket.send()
```

example

```
import socket
import os

def main():
    file_ori = 'Location of file to send'
    address = 'Destination IP'
    port = 'Destintion Port'

    clients_socket = socket.socket(socet.AF_INET, socet.SOCK_STREAM)
    client_socet.connect((adrees,int(port))

    file = open(file_ori, "rb")
    file_size = os.path.getsize(file_ori)
    data = file.read(file_size)
    file.close()

    client_socket.sendall(data)
    client_socket.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

if you want to send a value,

```
BHP = 'hello world'
#BHP = str(5.3482)  if you want to send a number, change it's type to string first.
data = BHP.encode()
client_socet.sendall(data)
```

you can do also

```
data = BHP.encode('utf-16')
```

if you want.

'utf-8' is default anyway.